# How to use jscrollpane with tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, jscrollpane

I am trying to use a jscrollpane in each of my tabs but only the first tab shows the scrollbars. See my code below: Hope someone can help, Many thanks. Philippe

$(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});

Comment: Could you provide the link to the website please? Or show the complete code?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, I think he is referring to JQueryUI tabs functionality.
It is a normal thing that only the visible tab gets the scroll-bar, I have the same problem.

This is because the other tabs are hidden and the JScrollPane can't calculate the size of the content. It returns zero, so he decides not to put a scroll-bar in there.

Please take a look at this [demo](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/invisibles.html) for using this plugin with invisible elements.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    show : function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.panel).jScrollPane();  
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the tabs function actually hides the divs, which need to be altered by the scroll function. A quick fix is to ensure the scroll function comes first.

```
$('#offers_content').jScrollPane(
       {
           verticalTrackHeight :100,
           verticalGutter   : 5
        }).css('padding','10px');   

$("#tabs").tabs();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using jQuery Layout plugin, and til now, its working fine. Here the example:
http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/tabs.html